# How to compute this derivative: $\frac{\partial}{\partial k}f(g(\cdot,k))$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

As the title already says, I am not sure how to differentiate 
$$
f(g(\cdot,k))
$$
to $k$.

I would like to know this derivative at $k=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the chain rule:

$$f^\prime(g(.,k))\frac{\partial}{\partial k} g(.,k)|_{k=0}$$